# MuiThemeProvider: How to use different themes for different routes?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I need to slightly change the theme depending on the current section of the site.

It seems that `MuiThemeProvider` only sets `muiTheme` on load; but it needs to be updated when the props change.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 3):

You can try to put the theme in a wrapping component that keeps the theme in it's state. Using [React's context](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html) this component exposes a function to child components to change the state.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';
import getMuiTheme from 'material-ui/styles/getMuiTheme';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import theme from './theme';
import themeOther from './theme-other'

class Wrapper extends Component {
  static childContextTypes = {
    changeTheme: PropTypes.func
  };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      muiTheme: getMuiTheme(theme)
    };
  }

  getChildContext() {
    return {changeTheme: this.changeTheme};
  }

  changeTheme = () => {
    this.setState({
      muiTheme: getMuiTheme(themeOther)
    })
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={this.state.muiTheme}>
        {this.props.children}
      </MuiThemeProvider>
    )
  }
}

export default Wrapper;
```

In some child component you can access the context and call the changeTheme function to set a different theme in the state. Make sure to include contextTypes else you can't access the function.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import RaisedButton from 'material-ui/RaisedButton';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

class ChildComponent extends Component {
  static contextTypes = {
    changeTheme: PropTypes.func
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <RaisedButton
        primary
        onTouchTap={this.context.changeTheme}
        label="Change The Theme"
      />
    );
  }
}

export default ChildComponent;
```

In the root of your app just render the wrapper.

```js
ReactDOM.render(
  <Wrapper>
    <App />
  </Wrapper>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

**EDIT:**
My first solution might have been abit too much. Since you are replacing the whole theme for the whole app. You can also use the MuiThemeProvider down the tree like so.

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import './index.css';
import inject from 'react-tap-event-plugin';
inject();

import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';
import getMuiTheme from 'material-ui/styles/getMuiTheme';
import theme from './theme';

ReactDOM.render(
  <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={getMuiTheme(theme)}>
    <App />
  </MuiThemeProvider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

In a child component you can just use the MuiThemeProvider again and override some properties. Note that these changes will reflect on all the children inside this MuiThemeProvider.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import RaisedButton from 'material-ui/RaisedButton';

import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';
import getMuiTheme from 'material-ui/styles/getMuiTheme';
import theme from './theme';
import { green800, green900 } from 'material-ui/styles/colors';

const localTheme = getMuiTheme(Object.assign({}, theme, {
  palette: {
    primary1Color: green800,
    primary2Color: green900
  }
}));

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>

        <RaisedButton
          primary
          label="Click"
        />


        <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={localTheme}>
          <RaisedButton
            primary
            label="This button is now green"
          />
        </MuiThemeProvider>


      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Is using context the only way to change the theme for the entire app, not just the daughter route?

Comment: Doesn't your context example use the old context API that will be removed?