# How to manipulate a variable in index.tsx (most parent) from other classes i.e NavBar component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I currently have my index.tsx as follows

```
const dark = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    type: 'dark',
  }
})

const light = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    type: 'light',
  }
})

const toggle:boolean = false;

ReactDOM.render(
  <MuiThemeProvider theme={toggle?dark:light}>
    <CssBaseline />
    <App />
  </MuiThemeProvider>,
  document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement
);
```

I have recently changed it so I could implement a dark-mode toggle, which happens at MuiThemeProvider.

The problem is I'm not sure how I could manipulate a boolean (toggle) varialbe at index.tsx (most parent file) where all my logic/codes are in App.tsx or especially on NavBar.tsx which is a component inside App.tsx which has a button to trigger the night-mode.

I've been only using React recently so I do know that I will have to use props to somehow escalate the value to the parent... but how does that actually happen and  is that the only correct way?

TLDR; How would I manipulate a variable at index from NavBar, given the architecture below? Also, it seems like index.tsx is a little different from others, as there is no class in it. If so what is the best way to keep track of a variable? Can I add a state just like every other component?
index > App > NavBar

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43924536/muithemeprovider-how-to-use-different-themes-for-different-routes) answer looks promising. You could use similar logic to toggle the boolean for each theme.

Comment: Amazing! Thanks for the sharing that link, I can definetly start from there. Apologies for not being a better searcher :/

Comment: Not a problem! Hope it helps. Post here again if you have any other concerns.